# EGMO 2015/P5: Let $m, n$ be positive integers with $m > 1$. Anastasia partitions the integers $1, 2, \dots , 2m$ into $m$ pairs.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $m, n$ be positive integers with $m > 1$. Anastasia partitions the integers $1, 2, \dots , 2m$ into $m$ pairs. Boris then chooses one integer from each pair and finds the sum of these chosen integers.
Prove that Anastasia can select the pairs so that Boris cannot make his sum equal to $n$.

My progress: A very beautiful question! Consider the partitions

$$P_1 = (\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, . . . , \{2m − 1, 2m\})$$

Note that this construction removes all numbers outside $[m^2, m^2+m]$ .

So we just have to find a construction in which numbers from $[m^2, m^2+m]$ is removed .

Apart from these observations , I got one more observation but I think it is not so useful.

Consider , $$P_2 = (\{1, m + 1\}, \{2, m + 2\}, . . . , \{m, 2m\})$$

This construction removes all numbers which are not of the form  $\tfrac 12 m(m+1) \pmod m$.

I will be really grateful if one can post hints and can guide me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand how $P_1$ is a partition into pairs. It just looks like a list of all the integers from $1$ to $2m$.

Comment: Yes, sorry , I forgot to give the brackets..Actually I gave curly brackets but when you give $ symbols , the curly bracket goes away..h

Comment: @Shubhangi: You need to use `\{` and `\}` to get curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two of your partitions don't work, then these two implies $n=m^2, m^2+m$ for odd $m$, and $m^2+m/2$ for even $m$. Consider the partition $$(1,m+2),(2,m+3),\ldots,(m-1,2m),(m,m+1)$$ This is $\tfrac{m(m-1)}{2}$ minus $0$ or $1$ mod $m+1$.

$\boxed{\text{Case 1: $m$ is odd}}$ The above becomes $\tfrac{1-m}{2}, \tfrac{-1-m}{2}\pmod{m+1}$. Since $m^2\equiv 1, m^2+m\equiv 0 \pmod{m+1}$, this proves there are no values of $n$ for odd $m$.

$\boxed{\text{Case 2: $m$ is even}}$ Then $$\tfrac{m(m-1)}{2} \equiv \tfrac{m}{2}\cdot (-2) \equiv 1 \pmod{m+1}$$ And $m^2+\tfrac{m}{2} \equiv 1+\tfrac{m}{2} \pmod{m+1}$. Now you can finish the proof.

Comment: In case OP just wants a hint, perhaps look here @Shubhangi :- https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1078899p4728599.

Comment: Thanks @Shamim , I totally forgot about AOPS cause I don't use it much .

Comment: Thanks @Shubrajit , I actually didn't think about this partition

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya thanks, your blog is great !

Comment: Not so great. I don't get time to post frequently but I have many things in mind.